# Pythonic way to append multiple values to a list

Tags: python, list, append

To be clear I have found some similar questions, but (to the best of my knowledge) none of them are either concise enough or exactly what I am looking for.

I have a list(of ints) and two other ints, and want to make them all into one list. Right now I have:

```
old_list = [1, 2, 3]
first_int = 3
second_int = 5

new_list = old_list
new_list.append(first_int)
new_list.append(second_int) 

# new_list == [1, 2, 3, 3, 5]
```

I feel that there is a more Pythonic way to do this but I am unsure exactly how.
The order of 'new_list' is not important.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You `extend` a list, for example:

```
new_list.extend([first_int, second_int])
```

By the way, your code also modifies `old_list` because `new_list` is just a reference to `old_list`.

If you really want a new list:

```
new_list = old_list[:]
```

Comment: The code modifying old_list is a typo on my part.  Before when I actually wanted a new list and not a reference to the previous one I've been using `new_list = old_list.copy()` Is there a difference between that and what you've shown?